# How do I match nested tag?

Tags: html, css, pre

I need to match `pre` when it is under `long` class, like in here:

```
<div class="long highlight-text">
  <div class="highlight">
    <pre>
      some code
  </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried: `long.highlight.pre` -- but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: it should be more like: .long.highlight-text .highlight pre {}

Comment: You should specify the exact conditions for matching. The correct answer heavily depends on that. For example, should *any* `pre` element that is inside an element in class `long` be a match? If not, what other conditions do you want to impose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As from your test you seem to also want to include `.highlight` in the selector, I'd suggest this one :

```
.long .highlight pre
```

or if you just want to "match pre when it is under long class" :

```
.long pre
```

A space in `a b` means `b` is a descendant of `a`.

Here's [the official documentation on CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

Answer (score 2):

You need the **[`␣ combinator` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)**, which refers to all matching descendants (not necessarily direct childs):

```
.long pre
```

---

See, also, this page describing **[CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**
or the official **[CSS Selectors Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)**.

Comment: Be careful when you link to this site which is full of errors. You shouldn't let think it's a "reference".

Comment: I am not fond of this site, whose name should not be spoken (or writen) and I always try to link to MDN, but I find this particular page a very good (simple and clear) reference for CSS selectors. (This does not mean the rest of the site is a reference or anything.)

Comment: @dystroy: There you go, I added the official reference for everyone to be happy (and hopefully safer) :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use: `.long pre`. And read http://www.w3schools.com/css3/default.asp for detail.

Comment: Wschools should not be consulted for details, or for anything else, see http://w3fools.com

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela Thanks for your comment.  W3schools is really a troublesome resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try this selector for css

```
.long .highlight pre
```